# I could not choose PDF file in Android 8 Oreo (Huawei)

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and I am  trying to choose pdf file to upload to the server in an android application 
I have a problem with api>24 in Huawei phones 
I take look for similar problems in StackOverflow but did not solve my problem 
[like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51546617/in-android-8-oreo-intent-chooser-is-not-working-to-set-wallpaper)

this problem just with Huawei's phone 
I have tried to pick a file from Samsung oreo and everything is okay, 
but with Huawei, the activity crushed 
**my code**

```
   private void imageBrowse() {



    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Pdf"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }
    else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

        intent.setType("application/pdf");
      //  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
      //  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

      //  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Pdf"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }
}
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST){
            Uri picUri = data.getData();



            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                filePath = getPath(this,picUri);

            }


            NAME = getPathfromURI(picUri);
            AlertDialog.Builder a_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Teacher_upload_files.this);
            a_builder.setMessage("اسم الملف :"+NAME)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             fileName.setText(NAME);
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = a_builder.create();
            alert.setTitle("شكرا :) ");
            alert.show();

            Log.d("picUri", picUri.toString());
          //  Log.d("filePath", filePath);

         //   imageView.setImageURI(picUri);

        }

    }

}
```

**this is how I get the path**

```
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

**the problem is here always null**

```
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

**and this is the error**

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/4736 flg=0x43 }} to activity {com.am.ahmad/com.am.ahmad.Teacher_upload_files}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI: content://downloads/public_downloads/4736
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4932)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4975)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1950)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI: content://downloads/public_downloads/4736
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:165)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:418)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:766)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:716)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:667)
    at com.am.ahmad.Teacher_upload_files.getDataColumn(Teacher_upload_files.java:593)
    at com.am.ahmad.Teacher_upload_files.getPath(Teacher_upload_files.java:536)
    at com.am.ahmad.Teacher_upload_files.onActivityResult(Teacher_upload_files.java:372)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7690)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4928)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4975) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1950) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

Comment: any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting a full solution for converting the Uri to File or file path, it works across all APIs and media libraries.

```kotlin
/*
* Copyright (C) 2018 OpenIntents.org
*
* Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
* You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
*      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
* limitations under the License.
*/

    object FileHelperKt {

    private const val DOCUMENTS_DIR = "documents"
    // configured android:authorities in AndroidManifest (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider)
    private const val AUTHORITY = "YOUR_AUTHORITY.provider"
    private const val HIDDEN_PREFIX = "."

    private val DEBUG = false // Set to true to enable logging
    /**
     * File and folder comparator. TODO Expose sorting option method
     */
    var sComparator = { f1: File, f2: File ->
        // Sort alphabetically by lower case, which is much cleaner
        f1.name.toLowerCase().compareTo(
            f2.name.toLowerCase()
        )
    }
    /**
     * File (not directories) filter.
     */
    var sFileFilter = { file: File ->
        val fileName = file.getName()
        // Return files only (not directories) and skip hidden files
        file.isFile() && !fileName.startsWith(HIDDEN_PREFIX)
    }
    /**
     * Folder (directories) filter.
     */
    var sDirFilter = { file: File ->
        val fileName = file.name
        // Return directories only and skip hidden directories
        file.isDirectory && !fileName.startsWith(HIDDEN_PREFIX)
    }

    val downloadsDir: File
        get() = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)

    /**
     * Gets the extension of a file name, like ".png" or ".jpg".
     *
     * @param uri
     * @return Extension including the dot("."); "" if there is no extension;
     * null if uri was null.
     */
    fun getExtension(uri: String?): String? {
        if (uri == null) {
            return null
        }

        val dot = uri.lastIndexOf(".")
        return if (dot >= 0) {
            uri.substring(dot)
        } else {
            // No extension.
            ""
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return Whether the URI is a local one.
     */
    fun isLocal(url: String?): Boolean {
        return url != null && !url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")
    }

    /**
     * @return True if Uri is a MediaStore Uri.
     * @author paulburke
     */
    fun isMediaUri(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "media".equals(uri.authority!!, ignoreCase = true)
    }

    /**
     * Convert File into Uri.
     *
     * @param file
     * @return uri
     */
    fun getUri(file: File?): Uri? {
        return if (file != null) Uri.fromFile(file) else null
    }

    /**
     * Returns the path only (without file name).
     *
     * @param file
     * @return
     */
    fun getPathWithoutFilename(file: File?): File? {
        if (file != null) {
            if (file.isDirectory) {
                // no file to be split off. Return everything
                return file
            } else {
                val filename = file.name
                val filepath = file.absolutePath

                // Construct path without file name.
                var pathwithoutname = filepath.substring(
                    0,
                    filepath.length - filename.length
                )
                if (pathwithoutname.endsWith("/")) {
                    pathwithoutname = pathwithoutname.substring(0, pathwithoutname.length - 1)
                }
                return File(pathwithoutname)
            }
        }
        return null
    }

    /**
     * @return The MIME type for the given file.
     */
    fun getMimeType(file: File): String? {
        val extension = getExtension(file.name)
        if (extension!!.isNotEmpty()) {
            return MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension.substring(1))
        } else {
            return "application/octet-stream"
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return The MIME type for the give Uri.
     */
    fun getMimeType(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
        val file = File(getPath(context, uri)!!)
        return getMimeType(file)
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is local.
     */
    fun isLocalStorageDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return AUTHORITY == uri.authority
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    fun isExternalStorageDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents" == uri.authority
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    fun isDownloadsDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents" == uri.authority
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    fun isMediaDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents" == uri.authority
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    fun isGooglePhotosUri(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content" == uri.authority
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
     * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri The Uri to query.
     * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
     * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
     * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
     */
    fun getDataColumn(context: Context, uri: Uri?, selection: String?, selectionArgs: Array<String>?): String? {

        var cursor: Cursor? = null
        val column = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA
        val projection = arrayOf(column)

        try {
            cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri!!, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null)
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                if (DEBUG)
                    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor)

                val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column)
                return cursor.getString(columnIndex)
            }
        } finally {
            cursor?.close()
        }
        return null
    }

    /**
     * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
     * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
     * other file-based ContentProviders.<br></br>
     * <br></br>
     * Callers should check whether the path is local before assuming it
     * represents a local file.
     *
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri The Uri to query.
     * @see .isLocal
     * @see .getFile
     */
    fun getPath(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
        Timber.d(
            "[app] FileHelper - Authority: ${uri.authority}, " +
                "Fragment: ${uri.fragment}, " +
                "Port: ${uri.port}, " +
                "Query: ${uri.query}, " +
                "Scheme: ${uri.scheme}, " +
                "Host: ${uri.host}, " +
                "Segments: ${uri.pathSegments}"
        )

        val isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // LocalStorageProvider
            if (isLocalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                // The path is the id
                return DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
            }
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            else if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val split = docId.split((":").toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
                val type = split[0]

                if ("primary".equals(type, ignoreCase = true)) {
                    return (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()).toString() + "/" + split[1]
                }
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                val id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                if (id != null && id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                    return id.substring(4)
                }
                val contentUriPrefixesToTry =
                    arrayOf("content://downloads/public_downloads", "content://downloads/my_downloads")
                for (contentUriPrefix in contentUriPrefixesToTry) {
                    val contentUri =
                        ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse(contentUriPrefix), java.lang.Long.valueOf(id!!))
                    try {
                        val path = getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null)
                        if (path != null) {
                            return path
                        }
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                    }
                }

                // path could not be retrieved using ContentResolver, therefore copy file to accessible cache using streams
                val fileName = getFileName(context, uri)
                val cacheDir = getDocumentCacheDir(context)
                val file = generateFileName(fileName, cacheDir)
                var destinationPath: String? = null
                if (file != null) {
                    destinationPath = file.absolutePath
                    saveFileFromUri(context, uri, destinationPath)
                }
                return destinationPath
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val split = docId.split((":").toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
                val type = split[0]

                var contentUri: Uri? = null
                when (type) {
                    "image" -> contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                    "video" -> contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                    "audio" -> contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                }

                val selection = "_id=?"
                val selectionArgs = arrayOf(split[1])

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs)
            }
        } else if ("content".equals(uri.scheme!!, ignoreCase = true)) {
            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri)) {
                return uri.lastPathSegment
            }
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null)
        } else if ("file".equals(uri.scheme!!, ignoreCase = true)) {
            return uri.path
        }

        return null
    }

    /**
     * Convert Uri into File, if possible.
     *
     * @return file A local file that the Uri was pointing to, or null if the
     * Uri is unsupported or pointed to a remote resource.
     * @author paulburke
     * @see .getPath
     */
    fun getFile(context: Context, uri: Uri?): File? {
        if (uri != null) {
            val path = getPath(context, uri)
            if (path != null && isLocal(path)) {
                return File(path)
            }
        }
        return null
    }

    /**
     * Get the file size in a human-readable string.
     *
     * @param size
     * @return
     * @author paulburke
     */
    fun getReadableFileSize(size: Int): String {
        val bytesInKilobytes = 1024
        val dec = DecimalFormat("###.#")
        val kb = " KB"
        val mb = " MB"
        val gb = " GB"
        var fileSize = 0f
        var suffix = kb

        if (size > bytesInKilobytes) {
            fileSize = (size / bytesInKilobytes).toFloat()
            if (fileSize > bytesInKilobytes) {
                fileSize /= bytesInKilobytes
                if (fileSize > bytesInKilobytes) {
                    fileSize /= bytesInKilobytes
                    suffix = gb
                } else {
                    suffix = mb
                }
            }
        }
        return (dec.format(fileSize.toDouble()) + suffix).toString()
    }

    /**
     * Get the Intent for selecting content to be used in an Intent Chooser.
     *
     * @return The intent for opening a file with Intent.createChooser()
     */
    fun createGetContentIntent(): Intent {
        // Implicitly allow the user to select a particular kind of data
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        // The MIME data type filter
        intent.type = "*/*"
        // Only return URIs that can be opened with ContentResolver
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        return intent
    }

    /**
     * Creates View intent for given file
     *
     * @param file
     * @return The intent for viewing file
     */
    fun getViewIntent(context: Context, file: File): Intent {
        // Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, AUTHORITY, file)
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        val url = file.toString()
        if (url.contains(".doc") || url.contains(".docx")) {
            // Word document
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/msword")
        } else if (url.contains(".pdf")) {
            // PDF file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf")
        } else if (url.contains(".ppt") || url.contains(".pptx")) {
            // Powerpoint file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint")
        } else if (url.contains(".xls") || url.contains(".xlsx")) {
            // Excel file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-excel")
        } else if (url.contains(".zip") || url.contains(".rar")) {
            // WAV audio file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/x-wav")
        } else if (url.contains(".rtf")) {
            // RTF file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/rtf")
        } else if (url.contains(".wav") || url.contains(".mp3")) {
            // WAV audio file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/x-wav")
        } else if (url.contains(".gif")) {
            // GIF file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/gif")
        } else if (url.contains(".jpg") || url.contains(".jpeg") || url.contains(".png")) {
            // JPG file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg")
        } else if (url.contains(".txt")) {
            // Text file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/plain")
        } else if ((url.contains(".3gp") || url.contains(".mpg") || url.contains(".mpeg") ||
                url.contains(".mpe") || url.contains(".mp4") || url.contains(".avi"))
        ) {
            // Video files
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*")
        } else {
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*")
        }

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
        return intent
    }

    fun getDocumentCacheDir(context: Context): File {
        val dir = File(context.cacheDir, DOCUMENTS_DIR)
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs()
        }
        logDir(context.cacheDir)
        logDir(dir)

        return dir
    }

    private fun logDir(dir: File) {
        if (!DEBUG) return
        Timber.d("[app] FileHelper log dir=$dir")
        val files = dir.listFiles()
        for (file in files!!) {
            Timber.d("[app] FileHelper path:${file.path}")
        }
    }

    fun generateFileName(name: String?, directory: File): File? {
        var name: String? = name ?: return null

        var file = File(directory, name!!)

        if (file.exists()) {
            var fileName: String = name
            var extension = ""
            val dotIndex = name.lastIndexOf('.')
            if (dotIndex > 0) {
                fileName = name.substring(0, dotIndex)
                extension = name.substring(dotIndex)
            }

            var index = 0

            while (file.exists()) {
                index++
                name = "$fileName($index)$extension"
                file = File(directory, name)
            }
        }

        try {
            if (!file.createNewFile()) {
                return null
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Timber.w(e, "[app] FileHelper")
            return null
        }

        logDir(directory)

        return file
    }

    /**
     * Writes response body to disk
     *
     * @param body ResponseBody
     * @param path file path
     * @return File
     */
    fun writeResponseBodyToDisk(body: ResponseBody, path: String): File? {
        try {
            val target = File(path)

            var inputStream: InputStream? = null
            var outputStream: OutputStream? = null

            try {
                val fileReader = ByteArray(4096)

                inputStream = body.byteStream()
                outputStream = FileOutputStream(target)

                while (true) {
                    val read = inputStream!!.read(fileReader)

                    if (read == -1) {
                        break
                    }

                    outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read)
                }

                outputStream.flush()

                return target
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                return null
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close()
                }

                if (outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.close()
                }
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            return null
        }
    }

    private fun saveFileFromUri(context: Context, uri: Uri, destinationPath: String) {
        var inputStream: InputStream? = null
        var bos: BufferedOutputStream? = null
        try {
            inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
            bos = BufferedOutputStream(FileOutputStream(destinationPath, false))
            val buf = ByteArray(1024)
            inputStream!!.read(buf)
            do {
                bos.write(buf)
            } while (inputStream.read(buf) != -1)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
            try {
                inputStream?.close()
                bos?.close()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

    fun readBytesFromFile(filePath: String): ByteArray? {
        var fileInputStream: FileInputStream? = null
        var bytesArray: ByteArray? = null

        try {
            val file = File(filePath)
            bytesArray = ByteArray(file.length().toInt())

            // read file into bytes[]
            fileInputStream = FileInputStream(file)
            fileInputStream.read(bytesArray)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
            if (fileInputStream != null) {
                try {
                    fileInputStream.close()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }

        return bytesArray
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun createTempImageFile(context: Context, fileName: String): File {
        // Create an image file name
        val storageDir = File(context.cacheDir, DOCUMENTS_DIR)
        return File.createTempFile(fileName, ".jpg", storageDir)
    }

    fun getFileName(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
        val mimeType = context.contentResolver.getType(uri)
        var filename: String? = null

        if (mimeType == null) {
            val path = getPath(context, uri)
            if (path == null) {
                filename = getName(uri.toString())
            } else {
                val file = File(path)
                filename = file.name
            }
        } else {
            val returnCursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)
            if (returnCursor != null) {
                val nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
                returnCursor.moveToFirst()
                filename = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex)
                returnCursor.close()
            }
        }

        return filename
    }

    fun getName(filename: String?): String? {
        if (filename == null) {
            return null
        }
        val index = filename.lastIndexOf('/')
        return filename.substring(index + 1)
    }
    }
```